# Python Error: json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 2 column 1 (char 2) when json.loads a valid json file

Tags: python, json

I am trying to load a valid json file (according to jsonlint.com) into python to then index it into elasticsearch.

MY CODE:

```
file = open(json_file)
i=1
json_data = [json.loads(line) for line in file]
print(json_data)
```

ERROR I AM RECEIVING:

```
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 2 column 1 (char 2)
```

I have checked other's solutions which focus on the invalidity of the json file but mine is completely valid.

SHORTENED VERSION OF MY JSON FILE:

```
[
  {"sepalLength": 5.1, "sepalWidth": 3.5, "petalLength": 1.4, "petalWidth": 0.2, "species": "setosa"},
  {"sepalLength": 4.9, "sepalWidth": 3.0, "petalLength": 1.4, "petalWidth": 0.2, "species": "setosa"},
  {"sepalLength": 4.7, "sepalWidth": 3.2, "petalLength": 1.3, "petalWidth": 0.2, "species": "setosa"},
  {"sepalLength": 4.6, "sepalWidth": 3.1, "petalLength": 1.5, "petalWidth": 0.2, "species": "setosa"}
]
```

I have no idea what seems to be the problem here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your list comprehension is trying to load as many objects as there are lines in your file, but there is just one file. Use this:

```
import json

with open(json_file, 'r') as f:
    json_data = [line for line in json.load(f)]
    print(json_data)
```